# Is Phillip Banks Hilary's father?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-fresh-prince-of-bel-air

I'm trying to determine if this is just a goof in details or if Hilary Banks was actually not Phillip Banks' daughter.

- Vivian Banks [birthday is October 21, 1951](https://freshprince.fandom.com/wiki/Vivian_Banks)
- Hilary Banks [birthday is May 25, 1969](https://freshprince.fandom.com/wiki/Hilary_Banks) (this means Vivian was not quite 18 yet when Hilary was born)
- [Phillip and Vivian got engaged on an episode of *Soul Train*](https://freshprince.fandom.com/wiki/Vivian_Banks)
- The first episode of *Soul Train* [aired in 1971](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0161194/)

If all of these facts are true, then it means Hilary was born at least two years before Phil and Vivian got engaged. It would also mean Vivian was underage when she got pregnant while Phil would have been 24.

So is this a goof or was Hilary not Phillip's daughter or did Phil and Vivian have a baby before they got married?

Comment: Your link says they got engaged on an episode of Soul Train. It doesn't say that is where they first met.

Comment: Good point, I updated the question

Comment: The episode aired in 1994, which wasn't 25 years after the start of Soul Train. Don Cornelius played himself as the host of Soul Train, yet he had left the show in 1993. The scrabble board doesn't have enough letters for Philip to spell out his marriage proposal. In an earlier episode Philip had said he went down on one knee to propose, yet he didn't. Goofs? Sure. Part of it is https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ComicBookTime , part of it is "the joke comes first", etc.

Comment: I'm with @BCdotWEB on this one.  TV shows in the 90s (*especially sitcoms*) were not nearly as vigilant about these sorts of continuity errors as they are nowadays.  That's not to say there was *zero* effort to avoid them, but there wasn't really much.

Comment: Seems like a really good answer.